# Ruby SFTP client

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I'm on Ruby for three weeks and now I want to learn more.
Please review this SFTP client and suggest any necessary changes.

```
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.

# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.

# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

# What is Net::SFTP?

# Net::SFTP is a pure-Ruby implementation of the SFTP protocol. 
# That’s “SFTP” as in “Secure File Transfer Protocol”, as defined as an adjuct to the SSH specification. 
# Not “SFTP” as in “Secure FTP” (a completely different beast). 
# Nor is it an implementation of the “Simple File Transfer Protocol” (which is in no way secure).

require 'net/sftp'
require 'ostruct'
require 'optparse'

class Christina

  Script = "Script => (christina.rb)"
  Version = "Version => (0.0.1)"

  def run(arguments)
    parse(arguments)
    connect(arguments)
  end

  private

  def parse(arguments)
    ARGV << "-h" if ARGV.empty?
    @options = OpenStruct.new
    
    args = OptionParser.new do |args|
      args.banner = "Usage: #{__FILE__} [options]"
      
      args.on("-s", "--set-host=HOST", String,
         "The Host To Connect To") do |set_host|
         @options.set_host = set_host
      end
      
      args.on("-u", "--username=USERNAME", String,
         "Authenticate With A Username") do |username|
         @options.username = username
      end

      args.on("-p", "--password=PASSWORD", String,
         "Authenticate With A Password") do |password|
         @options.password = password
      end

      args.on("-w", "--wharf=WHARF", Integer,
         "Specify The Wharf (Port) The Service Is Running") do |wharf|
         @options.wharf = wharf
      end

      args.on("-t", "--transfer=FILE", String,
         "Upload An Entire File On Disk") do |transfer|
         @options.transfer = transfer
      end

      args.on("-d", "--destination=FILE", String,
         "Destination For The Uploaded File") do |destination|
         @options.destination = destination
      end

      args.on("-m", "--mkdir=CREATE DIRECTORY", String,
         "Create A Directory") do |mkdir|
         @options.mkdir = mkdir
      end

      args.on("-r", "--rmdir=REMOVE DIRECTORY", String,
         "Remove A Directory") do |rmdir|
         @options.rmdir = rmdir
      end

      args.on("-q", "--query=FILE", String,
         "Query A File’s Permissions") do |query|
         @options.query = query
      end

      args.on("-e", "--erase=FILE", String,
         "Delete A File") do |erase|
         @options.erase = erase
      end

      args.on("-c", "--change=FILE", String,
         "Change A File’s Permissions") do |change|
         @options.change = change 
      end

      args.on("-a", "--authorization=INTEGER", Integer,
         "Combine With The Above Command To Change A File's Permissions") do |authorization|
         @options.authorization = authorization
      end

      args.on("-b", "--brand=FILE", String,
         "Brand (Rename) A File") do |name|
         @options.name = name
      end

      args.on("-n", "--new=FILE", String,
         "The Name Off The Renamed File") do |new|
         @options.new = new
      end

      args.on("-l", "--list=DIRECTORY", String,
         "Query The Contents Of A Directory") do |list|
         @options.list = list
      end

      args.on("-g", "--grab=FILE", String,
         "Grab Data Off The Remote Host Directly To A Buffer") do |grab|
         @options.grab = grab
      end

      args.on("-f", "--file=FILE", String,
         "Download Directly To A Local File") do |file|
         @options.file = file
      end

      args.on("-o", "--output=FILE", String,
         "Destination Off The Downloaded File") do |output|
         @options.output = output
      end

      args.on("-h", "--help", "Show Help And Exit") do
        puts args
        exit
      end

      args.on("-V", "--version", "Show Version And Exit") do
        puts Script
        puts Version
        exit      
      end

      begin
        args.parse!(arguments)
      
      rescue OptionParser::MissingArgument => error
        puts "[!] => #{error.message}"
        exit

      rescue OptionParser::InvalidOption => error
        puts "[!] => #{error.message}"
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  def connect(arguments)
    output("----------------------------------------------------------")
    output("[*] Starting at => #{Time.now}")
    output("[*] Operating System => #{RUBY_PLATFORM}")
    output("----------------------------------------------------------")

    output("[i] Connecting to Secure SHell")
    output("\t-- Host => #{@options.set_host}")
    output("\t-- Username => #{@options.username}")
    output("\t-- Password => #{@options.password}")
    output("\t-- Wharf => #{@options.wharf}")
    output("----------------------------------------------------------")

    Net::SFTP.start(@options.set_host, @options.username, :password => @options.password, :port => @options.wharf) do |sftp|
      mkdir(sftp) if @options.mkdir
      rmdir(sftp) if @options.rmdir
      remove(sftp) if @options.erase         
      query(sftp) if @options.query
      list(sftp) if @options.list
      grab(sftp) if @options.grab
      rename(sftp) if @options.name || @options.new
      change(sftp) if @options.change || @options.authorization
      upload(sftp) if @options.transfer || @options.destination
      download(sftp) if @options.file || @options.output
    end

    output("----------------------------------------------------------")
    output("[*] Exiting at => #{Time.now}")
    output("----------------------------------------------------------")
  end

  def mkdir(sftp)
    sftp.mkdir!(@options.mkdir)
    output("[i] Creating Directory => #{@options.mkdir}")
  end

  def rmdir(sftp)
    sftp.rmdir!(@options.rmdir)     
    output("[i] Removing Directory => #{@options.rmdir}")
  end

  def remove(sftp)
    sftp.remove!(@options.erase)
    output("[i] Removing File => #{@options.erase}")
  end

  def query(sftp)
    output("[i] Checking Permissions => #{sftp.stat!(@options.query).permissions}")
  end

  def grab(sftp)
    sftp.download!(@options.grab)
    output("[i] Grabing File => #{@options.grab}")
  end

  def rename(sftp)
    sftp.rename!(@options.name, @options.new)
    output("[i] Renaming File => #{@options.name}")
    output("[i] New File => #{@options.new}")
  end

  def change(sftp)
    sftp.setstat!(@options.change, :permissions => @options.authorization)
    output("[i] Setting Permissions To => #{@options.change}")
    output("[i] Permissions Set To => #{@options.authorization}")
  end

  def upload(sftp)  
    sftp.upload!(@options.transfer, @options.destination)
    output("[i] Uploading File To => #{@options.set_host}")
    output("\t-- Local File => #{@options.transfer}")
    output("\t-- File Destination => #{@options.destination}")
  end

  def download(sftp)
    sftp.download!(@options.file, @options.output)
    output("[i] Downloading File From => #{@options.set_host}")
    output("\t-- Remote File => #{@options.file}")
    output("\t-- File Destination => #{@options.output}")
  end

  def list(sftp)
    output("[i] Listing Contents Of => #{@options.list}")
    output("----------------------------------------------------------")
    sftp.dir.foreach(@options.list) do |entry|
    output(entry.longname)
  end
end

  def output(string)
    puts "#{string}"
  end
end

sftp = Christina.new
sftp.run(ARGV)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... under the terms of the GNU General Public License ...

IANAL, TINLA.
As copyright holder you [chose](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)
to license the code in your posting under the terms of
[CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/),
which is incompatible with GPLv3 as it does not allow authors to

> ... legally restrict others from doing anything the [CC] license permits.

It's possible you would find the (more permissive)
MIT or 2-clause BSD licenses to your liking.

tl;dr: These lines do not appear to have their intended effect, in the review context.

The CC folks have
[this](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/ShareAlike_compatibility:_GPLv3#How_one-compatibility_operates)
to say about porting code between licenses,
which apparently would go somewhat smoothly
had you tried to do it in the opposite direction:

> People may *not* adapt a GPLv3-licensed work and use BY-SA to license their contributions. This is not allowed by GPLv3. Thus, this compatibility determination only allows movement one way, from BY-SA 4.0 to GPLv3.

---

A concise "RFC913" citation for that third protocol wouldn't hurt.

For the first and second protocols, I *think* that you
are respectively referring to these?

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_FTP_(software)

But documentation shouldn't be a guessing game.
Spell it out for us.
Cite your references.

---

The "public" `run` vs "private" implementation is a nice touch. Thank you.

---

```
         @options.set_host = set_host
```

I don't understand why the UI doesn't offer a `--host` option,
but whatever. Even if that remains unchanged,
consider assigning just `@options.host`.

```
      args.on("-w", "--wharf=WHARF", Integer,
```

This term doesn't appear in section 4 of rfc1192.
Recommend that you

1. Explicitly identify the target audience you're addressing, whichever community would customarily use "wharf" as a 16-bit socket identifier, and
2. Add a `--port` synonym which has the same effect.

nit: Consider Using Fewer Capital Letters In The Help Text.

```
      args.on("-p", "--password=PASSWORD", String,
```

This is a tricky one.
What you have there is fine, don't change it.
But some folks will look for the ability to have
a non-echoing interactive prompt.
And a more common practice is to pull such credentials
from an exported environment variable.
There's also config files like `~/.netrc`

```
      args.on("-t", "--transfer=FILE", String,
```

Honestly, these are starting to sound less like "options"
and more like "commands".
You have a bunch of them.
And I can envision a caller wanting to execute several
of them once they've spent some time setting up an SSH connection.
If caller specifies `-t A.txt -t B.txt` it's pretty clear
they'll only get the second file.
Consider supporting a list of commands?
Or reading commands from a file, such as stdin?

typo ("of"):

```
         "The Name Off The Renamed File") do |new|
```

---

```
      rescue OptionParser::MissingArgument => error
        ...
      rescue OptionParser::InvalidOption => error
```

[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
Maybe we can combine the `puts` behavior, here?

Also, think about the diagnostic value of the message.
Maybe the person viewing it would benefit from a
reminder that `--help` is available?

---

```
    output("[*] Operating System => #{RUBY_PLATFORM}")
```

Consider clarifying that this is the **local** OS.

```
      remove(sftp) if @options.erase         
      query(sftp) if @options.query
```

Hmmm, that seems undesirable.
If I was reading the `--help` output, I might believe
that query happens before erase, but it turns out that is not so.
And we also see such inconsistencies in "list" and others.
There is a design choice to be made, here.
Consider adopting either

1. Args validation limits the caller to just a single verb, or
2. Args support a **list** of verbs to execute in sequence.

```
      rename(sftp) if @options.name || @options.new
      change(sftp) if @options.change || @options.authorization
      upload(sftp) if @options.transfer || @options.destination
      download(sftp) if @options.file || @options.output
```

Sorry, I don't find those obvious.
Oh, wait, I just viewed the
[docs](https://rubydoc.info/gems/net-sftp/2.0.5/Net/SFTP/Protocol/V02/Base#rename-instance_method).
At least some of those require that *both* args be
specified, right? And we've not done any local validation
along those lines, yet. IDK, maybe the `rename` method
being called gives an appropriate diagnostic message to the user when only a single arg appeared on the command line?

```
    output("[*] Exiting at => #{Time.now}")
```

This is lovely.
Maybe displaying the elapsed time is also of interest to caller?

---

```
    sftp.mkdir!(@options.mkdir)
    output("[i] Creating Directory => #{@options.mkdir}")
```

In each of these methods, the order seems backwards.
Consider telling the user *before* executing the verb,
in case something goes wrong and it blows up.

Alternatively, announce the fait accompli in the past tense,
with "Created".

Also, ruby offers a lovely
[logger](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/exts/syslog/Syslog/Logger.html).
Consider using it, so callers can reliably parse your output.

And, oh yeah. Everything that @papirtiger said!

Comment: IANAL TINLA for the first paragraph? IANAL TINLA Your first paragraph doesn't acknowladge the possibility to dual licence, making your point moot. Additionally I'm pretty sure a good lawyer would plead breaking the TOS rather than breaking CC BY-SA. TOS are basically only important if you want to stay on the service. Also we'd also have to ignore [the licence compatibility](https://creativecommons.org/2015/10/08/cc-by-sa-4-0-now-one-way-compatible-with-gplv3/).

Answer (score 2):

It's a decent first attempt but the way you have structured the code leaves a lot to be desired. As @J_H has covered the nitty gitty pretty well I'm just going to go over the broad conceptual issues.

A big problem here is the destribution of responsibilites.

Everything is just tossed in the cryptically named Christina class (why is it called Christina?) which does everything from parsing command line arguments to handling connections and actually manipulating files. Its a textbook god class.

Split this up into classes that have a [single defined responisibity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

If you're writing code to be reused in Ruby its done though gems. Gems have a set of conventions such as the Gemspec that contains information about the gem as well as list of dependencies and the binaries provided by a gem.

Gems typically have a main module as their namespace and the rest of the code in logically nested under that module.

You might want to start working towards a structure that is more like:

```
# lib/christina.rb

require 'ostruct'
require 'optparse'
require 'net/sftp'
require 'zeitwerk' # this gem must be installed since its not in the stdlib (yet)

# This will automatically require all the files in the project for 
# you as long as you follow its conventions
# @see https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk
loader = Zeitwerk::Loader.for_gem
loader.setup # ready!

# Put the main description of the module here so that documentation tools can
# find it.
module Christina
  VERSION = '1.2.3' # constants should be allcaps unless they are classes or modules
end
```

```
# lib/christina/options_parser.rb
module Christina
  # Parses command line options - does't actually execute them
  class OptionsParser
    # What are the arguments?
    # What does this return?
    def self.parse(arguments)
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

```
# lib/christina/connection.rb
module Christina
  class Connection
    def initialize(host:, password:, **options)
      @host = host
      # ...
    end
    
    # runs the block within the connection   
    def with_connection(&block)
      Net::SFTP.start(connection_options) do |sftp|
        yield
      end
    end

    private 
    def connection_options
      { host: @host, password: @password } # ...
    end
  end
end
```

```
# lib/christina/command.rb
module Christina
  # this are the classes that actually perform the operations on the connection
  class Command
    # ...
  end
end
```

```
# lib/christina/command.rb
module Christina
  class Download < Command
    # ...
  end
end
```

While it might initalially feel easy and comforting to just bang your code out in a single file it doesn't result in code thats easy to maintain, test, reason about, or for others to understand.

You need to apply the same logic to your methods. A method should ideally just do a single job - its often hard enough to even get that right.

Document both the classes and your methods with either YARD or RDOC. Remember that you're writing code for future you. And future you will be very thankful.

### Some purely stylistic stuff:

- Adding your license to the code files themselves isn't very common in the Ruby community. Instead its done in a separate file in the root directory. One reason is that you would have to modify the entire project if you ever need to change the licence.
- Signing your work with constant is also somewhat odd. We share code though gems and your name / the names of the contributors is in the gemspec.

### Some recommendations:

- Start using Rubocop. It will hurt your feelings - but it will also make you write better Ruby.
- Write units tests and think about how to structure your code for testability.